# SyntaxError: Use of the "Var" keyword is disallowed

Tags: remix

someone could tell me how to define this function without using "var"? I don´t know if I have done it well. This is part of my code:

```
struct user{ 
        uint time_transation; 
        uint amount; 
        uint[24] price_of; 
        uint[24] price_de; 
        uint[24] price;
        uint tipo_usuario; 
        uint amountcasada;
        uint coinAccount;
        uint identificador;
    }
    mapping (address => user) usuarios;
    
 
    function setOwner(address DSO) public{
        owner=DSO;
    }
    
    modifier OnlyOwner{
        require(msg.sender==owner);
        _;
    }
function Input_prosumidor(uint _coinAccount) public{
        **var Usuario=usuarios[msg.sender];** //here is my error
        Usuario.time_transation=now;  
        usuariosAd.push(msg.sender) -1;
        Usuario.coinAccount=_coinAccount;
        Usuario.price_of=_precio_of;
        Usuario.price_de=_precio_de;
        Usuario.identificador=contadoridentificador;
        contadoridentificador++;
    }
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
var
```

To this:

```
user storage
```

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity there is no `var` keyword anymore (used to be until  0.4.20 https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.20). You have to explicitly declare all variables - you have to prefix them by the right type. So in your case you should write `user storage Usuario=usuarios[msg.sender];` as the type of `usuarios` is `mapping (address => user)`. The `storage` keyword is required because you have to (temporarily) store the value somewhere and you have to specify where it is stored.

Comment: I believe this won't work, since he's changing the contents of `Usuario`.

Comment: In addition to that, in Solidity there actually **was** a `var` keyword up until a certain point (at around solc 0.4.21 or so). So you probably wanna refine your opening statement, which implies as if this user got the idea out of wishful thinking.

Comment: Thanks :) always forget those keywords. edited.

Comment: another edit. been a million years since `var`, had totally forgotten it :)